# reverse() does not work on a Python literal?

Tags: python

Why doesn't this work in Python?

```
>>> print [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0].reverse() 
None
```

I expected to get back the list in reverse order.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want it to return a new list in reverse order, you can use `[::-1]`

```
>>> [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0][::-1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

As I'm still trying to understand the downvote, if it doesn't matter that the original list gets changed, use [@taskinoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827413/reverse-does-not-work-on-a-python-litteral/6827449#6827449), it'll be faster.

However if you're required to keep the original list unchanged, I suggest you to use `[::-1]`.

```
from time import time
lst = [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]

s = time()
for i in xrange(5000000):
    a = lst[::-1]          # creates a reversed list
print time() -s

s = time()
for i in xrange(5000000):
    b = lst[:]             # copies the list
    b.reverse()            # reverses it
print time() -s
```

outputs

```
2.44950699806
3.02573299408
```

Comment: (It wasn't I but) you haven't actually explained what is wrong with the OP's code.

Comment: Not only haven't you explained what's wrong with the OP's code, you haven't mentioned `reversed()`, which is the most straightforward option.  (I also did not downvote you, however.)

Comment: @katrielalex, taskinoor had already answered that question before. In my sense, the possibility to add multiple answers is not to have the same one multiple times. Also, I do not believe that writing the same thing using two different wordings would be considered as two different answers. taskinoor's answer is correct, I upvoted it. I just said something different. This is more like a suggestion that provides what the OP's expecting

Answer (score 52):

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 5]
>>> print a.reverse()
None
>>> a
[5, 4, 3]
>>>
```

It's because `reverse()` does not return the list, rather it reverses the list in place. So the return value of `a.reverse()` is `None` which is shown in the `print`.

Comment: Yes, this answers the OP's question, in the literal sense.  But clearly what he *wants* to do is get a reversed copy of his list.  So your answer would be complete if you added a recommendation for how to achieve that.  (My recommendation would be `reversed()`.)

Answer (score 22):

If you want reversed copy of a list, use [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
>>> list(reversed([1,2,3,4]))
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

p.s. `reversed` returns an iterator instead of copy of a list (as `[][::1]` does). So it is suitable then you need to iterate through a reversed iterable. Additional `list()` here used only for the demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement other answers. Do not forget:

```
>> reversed_iterator = reversed([0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0])
>> print list(reversed_iterator)
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

This way your list is unchanged if this is a requierement.

Answer (score 1):

reverse changes a list variable as seen here
[list reverse](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

if you print it after you reversed it it will show up correctily

so just use a variable