# How to reverse tuples in Python?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, tuples

Is this possible? Doesn't have to be in place, just looking for a way to reverse a tuple so I can iterate on it backwards.

Comment: Have you tried using `reversed` ?

Comment: There are lots of duplicates of this question, but they all seem to be asking about strings or lists istead of tuples. The answer is the same. Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827413/reverse-does-not-work-on-a-python-literal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python

Comment: This is not the same as reversing lists and imo stands as a reasonable question. There are additional considerations for `tuple`s including invoking `tuple()` on the outut.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the insinuations there. Exactly as agf said: The request was to reverse "so I can iterate on it backwards". The other question speaks of reversing a list (which is already ambiguous between "reverse in place" and "create a reversed copy") and *also* "looping over it backwards", i.e., iterating backwards. The only techniques that don't equally apply to tuples are the ones that reverse in-place, and it will be obvious that they don't work to anyone who tries, and obvious *why* to anyone who *knows what a tuple is in the first place*.

Comment: Redirecting people to a canonical improves the utility of the site. Novice Python programmers are *better served* by generalizing problems with sequences, rather than imagining that every little thing has to be done differently for lists vs tuples (vs. strings) - because the first is *much, much closer to the truth*. The answers here, mutatis mutandis, apply there (and would probably be duplicates, too). Anyway, if my philosophy were "deletionism", I would be casting delete votes. I reserve those for poorly asked or misleading questions that risk drawing traffic away from the better questions.

Comment: (I will be happy to discuss the matter further on Meta or in the Python chat room, but not here.)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

There are two idiomatic ways to do this:

```
reversed(x)  # returns an iterator
```

or

```
x[::-1]  # returns a new tuple
```

Since tuples are immutable, there is no way to reverse a tuple in-place.

---

**Edit:**
Building on @lvc's comment, the iterator returned by `reversed` would be equivalent to

```
def myreversed(seq):
    for i in range(len(x) - 1, -1, -1):
        yield seq[i]
```

i.e. it relies on the sequence having a known length to avoid having to actually reverse the tuple.

As to which is more efficient, i'd suspect it'd be the `seq[::-1]` if you are using all of it and the tuple is small, and `reversed` when the tuple is large, but performance in python is often surprising so measure it!

Comment: If you actually need to construct an output tuple, then you need to compare `tuple(reversed(x))` to `x[::-1]` for performance. If you simply want to iterate over the elements in reverse order, `reversed` has a much better chance of showing a performance improvement.

Comment: `reversed` is 21% faster for large tuples and 3% slower for small tuples. Since it's much more readable, I would use `reversed` for everything. I did `timeit.timeit("for i in x[::-1]: i * i", "x = tuple(range(1000000))", number=1000)` and `timeit.timeit("for i in x[::-1]: i * i", "x = tuple(range(3))", number=100000)`.

Comment: I prefer the `x[::-1]` one because it's handy.

Comment: @tobyodavies this one is beautiful: ```x[::-1]```. Such extended slices are well explained here: https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question given that the output is an `list_reverseiteator`

Comment: What are you talking about @javadba the second one is a tuple. Also the question says it wants to iterate over the tuple backwards. At no point does it say they actually want a tuple but I gave both an iterator and a tuple as possible return types.

Comment: Fair enough - I should have just commented instead that the first one would be better stated as `tuple(reversed(x))` as in the following answer. Not all of us will realize immediately that the `list_reverseiterator` simply needs `tuple` around it to get a list out of it.   I agree the downvote were not warranted but I can not "reverse" it  unless the answer is changed due to SOF rules aimed at handling abuse - but which are problematic in normal non-abuse situations such as this.  I generally disagree with `python3` having turned results into generators: it seriously decreases readability.

Comment: @javadba the question asks how to reverse a tuple (the input), it makes no statement as to the desired type of the output. It says they want to iterate over it backwards, in which case an iterator may be a more appropriate type. Hence the deliberate choice not to unnecessarily create a tuple, but to clearly provide the second option in case they did in fact want a tuple but did not say so.

Comment: If the tuples are of known length and really short it can even be more efficient to do the reversal explicitly:

```import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("(t[1], t[0])", "t = (1337, 42)", number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit("t[::-1]", "t = (1337, 42)", number=1000))```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `reversed` builtin function.

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x = tuple(reversed(x))
>>> x
(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

If you just want to iterate over the tuple, you can just use the iterator returned by `reversed` directly without converting it into a tuple again.

```
>>> for k in reversed(x):
...     print(k)
... 
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: yes this does fully answer the question by returning a `tuple`

Answer (score 7):

Similar to the way you would reverse a list, i.e. s[::-1]

```
In [20]: s = (1, 2, 3)

In [21]: s[::-1]
Out[21]: (3, 2, 1)
```

and

```
In [24]: for i in s[::-1]:
   ....:     print i
   ....:
3
2
1
```