# Why does calling __reversed__ upon a tuple throw an attribute error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

As I understand, one can call a magic method of an object in either of two ways. Firstly like this, where the magic method is called like any regular method:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
print(x.__len__())
#prints 4
```

And secondly, like this, where the magic method is called "specially":

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
print((len(x)))
#prints 4
```

As we can see, both are equivalent. However, when I call the magic method `reversed()` upon a tuple with the first way, I am met with an error:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
x.__reversed__()
#causes an attribute error
```

Yet the "special" way of calling the reversed method works perfectly fine:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
reversed(x)
#returns a reversed object
```

Why does this occur? Have I misunderstood something about dunder methods?

Comment: Similar: [Is there any case where `len(someObj)` does not call `someObj`'s `__len__` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496009/4518341)

Comment: Conventions say that you should not consider any method starting with an underscore as part of the public API of an object. Why? The observation in your question is a great example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most magic methods **are not** equivalent to whatever other thing they look like they should be equivalent to. `__add__` is not equivalent to `+`. `__iadd__` is not equivalent to `+=`. `__iter__` is not equivalent to `iter`. Neither `__getattribute__` nor `__getattr__` is equivalent to `getattr` (or ordinary attribute access).

Continuing the pattern, `__reversed__` is not equivalent to `reversed`. If `reversed` finds a `__reversed__` method, it'll use the method, but if not, it'll just make an iterator that accesses the argument from back to front with ordinary indexing. The sequence needs no `__reversed__` method, and `tuple` does not have one.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But what if I call iter on an object that doesn't have an __iter__ method? Wouldn't things go funky then?

Comment: @Dude156: `__iter__` has the same fallback `__reversed__` does, but indexing front to back instead of back to front.

Comment: But I mean if we call `iter()` when we don't have an `__iter__` for that object, how would the method know how to make an iterator...?

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that there must be an `__reversed__` method is wrong:

> `reversed(seq)`
>
> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a __reversed__() method **or** supports the sequence protocol (*the __len__() method and the __getitem__() method with integer arguments starting at 0*).

Answer (score 1):

Because `reversed` does one of the following depending on the argument:

1. Argument is an object with `__reversed__` magic method and `reversed` just calls it and returns given iterator.

```py
>>> class A:
...     def __reversed__(self):
...         yield 17
...         yield 42
>>> a = A()
>>> reversed(a)
<generator object A.__reversed__ at 0x7fa1283e8e40>
>>> list(reversed(a))
[17, 42]
```

2. Argument is a sequence (like `tuple` or `str`) that has `__len__` and `__getitem__` and `__reversed__` creates an intermediate object that yields elements of the sequence from the last to the first.

```py
>>> t = (42, 17)
>>> reversed(t)
<reversed object at 0x7fa12840fc40>
>>> list(reversed(t))
[17, 42]
```

From [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201977/how-to-reverse-tuples-in-python/10201993)

> `reversed(seq)`
>   Return a reverse iterator. `seq` must be an object which has a `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol (the `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer arguments starting at `0).

More generally you probably should not call dunder methods (because it is very dangerous way, especially in production code) and use special functions/classes for accessing them like `reversed`/`len`.